# Very slow java/json (~30RPS)

Tags: java, json, performance, jackson

I have a Go program starting a Java server and communicates with it over TCP with JSON.

My problem is that it is very slow, on my machine I get about 30 requests per second.

If I just pass the same data without JSON decoding/encoding I get about 29,000 requests per second.

I'm using jackson 2.9.0 and would love to know how I can speed up my code.

I have a full benchmark [here][1], here are the Java encoding/decoding bits:

EventReader.java

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser.Feature;

public class EventReader {
    private ObjectMapper mapper;
    private InputStream in;

    public EventReader(InputStream in) {
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(Feature.AUTO_CLOSE_SOURCE, false);
        this.in = in;
    }

    public JsonEvent next() throws Throwable {
        try {
            return mapper.readValue(in, JsonEvent.class);
        } catch (IOException e){
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

ResponseEncoder.java

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Map;

public class ResponseEncoder {
    private BufferedOutputStream out;
    private ObjectMapper mapper;
    JsonGenerator gen;


    public ResponseEncoder(OutputStream out) throws Throwable{
        JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();
        this.out = new BufferedOutputStream(out);
        this.gen = factory.createGenerator(out);
        this.mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        this.mapper.configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.AUTO_CLOSE_TARGET, false);
    }

    public void encode(Response response) throws IOException {

        this.out.write('r');

        this.gen.writeStartObject();
        this.gen.writeNumberField("status_code", response.getStatusCode());
        this.gen.writeStringField("content_type", response.getContentType());
        this.gen.writeBinaryField("body", response.getBody());
        this.gen.writeStringField("body_encoding", "base64");

        this.gen.writeFieldName("headers");
        this.gen.writeStartObject();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : response.getHeaders().entrySet()) {
            this.gen.writeObjectField(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
        this.gen.writeEndObject();

        this.gen.writeEndObject();
        this.gen.flush();
        this.out.write('\n');
        this.out.flush();
    }
}
```

1] https://github.com/tebeka/java-json-tcp-bench

Comment: Which part of this exactly are you looking for help here? Can you add a clear problem statement?

Comment: Please show the benchmark results. No one wants to dl dependencies, clone a repo, & run a test that may take a while to complete just to see results you could personally show us.

Comment: After looking through the code, honestly, it kind of makes sense to me. I don't know exactly what the JsonGenerator does under the hood, but it looks like there is A LOT more processing per request which is naturally going to bog it down. Are you saying this number of requests seems abnormal?

Comment: So you found your own code is slow?  Time to find out why, and if you need it.

Comment: @Avery I'd like to get my code faster. I *suspect* it's slow JSON serialization but not sure.

Comment: @VinceEmigh There results are there. 29,000 RPS without JSON, 30 with JSON.

Comment: @kunruh IMO yes. jackson should be much, much faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've replaced jackson with [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson), performance got up to 17,300RPS.

If you're interested, [code is at the same place](https://github.com/tebeka/java-json-tcp-bench).

Answer (score 0):

It is bit unclear exactly how measurements are done (or, more specifically, over what kind of data set), but basic rule on Java/JVM benchmarking is that there is big difference with first call (and in general first couple of seconds of operation), and steady-state performance.

So for servers and long-running processes it is absolutely necessary to measure steady-state; otherwise you will just measure warmup time for JVM and libraries in question.
Jackson, for example, has relatively high initial cost when it accesses all `Class` metadata via reflection, annotations and so on.
So just from your results I am pretty sure you are measuring startup overhead more than anything else.
The only other possibility I can think of is that if test managed to create new `ObjectMapper` for each request, that would slow things down by factor of 100x - 1000x.

Aside from that GSON is not faster for steady-state operation (as per almost any Java/JSON benchmark you can find). But it is fine library and is fast enough for typical use.

ps. Make sure to reuse `ObjectMapper` between reads -- looking at code above, `InputStream` varies, but mapper absolutely should be reused. Its construction is expensive, and all handlers are cached by mapper. One static instance per app is typical. One per request would lead to numbers you quoted.